# Ionic StreamingMedia video player causes status bar to overlap on the header

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, overlap, ionic-native, video-player

I am having an issue with the StreamingMedia plugin.

When I play a video, and click “Done” to close the video player, the status bar in my app overlaps the header in all pages. I can assure that it’s not the header that is faulty, because I have a separate header on all pages.

The issue exists on iOS devices.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I'm the current maintainer of the plugin. Did you clone directly from the repo or from react native/npm?

What specific devices are you experiencing this on? Can you describe the behavior and how to reproduce it?

Comment: @TimothyShamilov I installed it using npm. The steps to reproduce are mentioned in my original post. Fortunately, I have found a fix for this issue. I stuck the ion-header component of my app to a specific margin-top focusing on the safe areas. Having done that, the headers no longer get repositioned after playing a video.

Comment: Do a fresh install of the latest version anyways (2.1.1). We've had a lot of updates in the past couple of weeks.